# How do I bypass the 255 character limit in the Word Combo Box?

Tags: combobox, ms-word

How do I bypass the 255 character limit in the Combo Box (MS Word). I am not using a database or anything "Complex". I am simply trying to enter a 300 character drop-down in the combo box. Is there an easy way to achieve this on MS Word without extensive programming knowledge etc?

Comment: **Why are you putting 300 characters in an combo box?** If you provide a little background it may be possible to help you in another way. May you just use the wrong control.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can only do a substitution. Means add representation of what it should contain and once you leave the combo box you actually insert the value you intend.